need to explain method of induction process and proof by induction in a certain example
On pages 2 and 3 he has Iheorem 1.3 and it's proof which i will link."Spherical Harmonics"
So in that proof where he says "Suppose the statement holds for m=0,1,...,n-1" what statement is he talking about? And by the induction process could one give example like if it's true for n=2 then what is it and what is it for n=3 and 4 and write exactly what it is and then keep going up giving exact statements of what it is as we progress at each stage say thru n=8. U can use dim $H_n^d\!+\!dim\,P_{n-2}^d\!=dim\,P_n^d$. I really can't understand the induction process in this particular example though i usually have been able to understand it in most other examples and proofs but this one is difficult to understand what exactly he means. Examples ,Examples please if you understand what it means here in this link theorem 1.3 on page 2 and it's proof on page 3. Another question that may help me understand better is in the direct sum notice the exponent of $||x||^{2j} H_{n-2j}^d$ changes by 2 in the sum. Why not sum terms such as $||x||^{j} H_{n-j}^d$ or is it because would then end up with irrational terms such as $\sqrt{...}$ which cannot be canceled or reduced ? Also for d,n all non-neg integers is it correct or incorrect to write
$0\!\subset\!P_{n}^d,0\!\subset\!H_{n}^d$ ?

The "inductive" statement/theorem in the link states:
For $n \in \mathbb W$ (i.e., $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$), there is always a decomposition of $P_n^d$.

ok yea i did add something to the question and then was able to delete my answer only. Though it always came out with 'are u sure u want to delete this post' so maybe it just meant the answer only anyway in all cases even though it used the word post.
